# Reference request: dependence on linear constraints

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming, global-optimization

Excuse me if my question is stupid. I'm seeking the references on the dependence of the (linear) optimization problem on (linear) constraints. Namely, consdier the following optimization problem:

$$P(\alpha)~~:=~~\sup_{p\in\mathcal A(\alpha)}~c^T p,$$

with

$$\mathcal A(\alpha)~~:=~~\big\{p\in\mathbb R^n:~ Ap~=~\alpha\big\},$$

where $\alpha\in\mathbb R^m$, $c\in\mathbb R^n$ and $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ are given. I'm looking for the references on the map $\alpha\longrightarrow P(\alpha)$. Any suggestions and comments are highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

PS: Thanks for the reply. Indeed, here we suppose of course that $m>n$ and actually $p_i\ge 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^np_i=1$. So if the set $\mathcal{A}(\alpha)\neq \emptyset$, then the maximizer always exists.

Answer (score 1):

The usual linear programming problem requires at least some variables to be nonnegative or has inequality constraints.  Here you only have equality constraints and $p \in \mathbb R^n$, so your feasible region (if nonempty) is an affine subspace, and in order for $P(\alpha)$ to be finite your $c^T$ must be a linear combination of the rows of $A$.  Then $P(\alpha)$ will be the corresponding linear combination of the entries of $\alpha$.  Also, any 
linear dependency of the rows of $A$ will correspond to a constraint on the entries of $\alpha$ required for feasibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider general linear programming problems and the solution in dependence on changes in the right hand side, you want to look for **sensitivity analysis in linear programming** and more specifically **changes in the right hand side**. Most books on linear programming cover this, e.g. chapter 3 in "[Applied Mathematical Programming](http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/)".